# Facebook Like Button - showing wrong images and contents

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I am using the following code to add Facebook Like button to my website :-

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXXXX%2FXXXXX%2FXXXXX.php%3Fid%3D<?php //echo $row['my_id'];  ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=104780909636116" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px; float:left; margin-top:14px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But after clicking the like button and when i look into my FB wall all i can see is some other image as well as other content from the same page, but not the one which i meant to like. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this? I am looking forward for some valuable suggestions.

Comment: if `http://XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX.php` doesn't lead to the right place, you could have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page specified in `href` attribute of Like Button should be publicly available and have OpenGraph meta tags including `og:url` which should be canonical URL pointing to page that represent "liked" content, if this isn't the same page, than one specified by `og:url` should have OpenGraph meta tags with content that will be published on user's feed.

You can ensure that correct data crawled by Facebook by passing URL of liked page to [Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)